# PHP: calculate hysteresis

Tags: php

I'm trying to calculate if heater need start or stop.

But I have some difficult with the control code:

```
$hysteresis = 0.5;

        $min_limit = $target_temperature-$hysteresis;
        $max_limit = $target_temperature+$hysteresis;

        if ($current_temperature<=$min_limit) {
            echo 'eseguito parte 1';
            return true;
        }

        if ($current_temperature>=$max_limit) {
            echo 'eseguito parte 2';
            return false;
        }
```

E.g for a target temperature == 21, heater need to start at 20.5 and stop at 21.5.

But with current_temperature == 21.2 (for example) neither of the code is executed.

How can I intercept also the intermediate case?

Thank you

EDIT:

Thank to the comments of Mike and Federkun:

```
if ( ( ($current_temperature<=$min_limit)===false ) && ( ($current_temperature>=$max_limit)===false ) ) {
            return true;        
        }
```

Comment: you said target_temp is 21 and current_temp is 21.2, i guess it's correct that no code is executed...

Comment: You just need to go through your logic. Is 21.5 less than the minimum limit? No. Is it greater than the max limit? No. You need to put some sort of condition when the temperature is between the minimum and maximum limits.

Comment: if your `$current_temperature` isn't <= of `$min_limit` nor >= of `$max_limit`, then you _are_ in the "intermediate case".

Comment: @Mike thank you. You did put me in right way. Can you check, please?

Comment: @Federkun same of Mike for you. Thank you. You did put me in right way. Can you check, please?

Comment: @sineverba Comparison operators (e.g. `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=`) **always** return a boolean. Don't compare the results to `=== false` because that is just confusing and makes your code more difficult to read. Just use the correct comparison operators.